# How to resolve error with Styleformer package in python

Tags: python-3.x, transformer-model

I am trying to install `styleformer` module in `Jupyter Notebook Server` having `Tensorflow 2.3` as kernel with `Python 3.6`

Module: https://github.com/PrithivirajDamodaran/Styleformer

Since there is no `internet` in server, I upload the `github file` in notebook from local and install this using `setup.py` file.

One problem is that I have to be always inside the `Styleformer` ( Note: `S` capital) folder to run this command

`from styleformer import Styleformer`

But as soon as I run this command:

`sf = Styleformer(style = 0)`

It gives the below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py in get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    241             if resolved_config_file is None:
--> 242                 raise EnvironmentError
    243             config_dict = cls._dict_from_json_file(resolved_config_file)

OSError: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/bin/kernel-launchers/python/scripts/launch_ipykernel.py in <module>
      1 from styleformer import Styleformer
----> 2 sf = Styleformer(style = 0)

~/Styleformer/styleformer/styleformer.py in __init__(self, style)
      7 
      8     self.style = style
----> 9     self.adequacy = Adequacy()
     10     self.model_loaded = False
     11 

~/Styleformer/styleformer/adequacy.py in __init__(self, model_tag)
      3   def __init__(self, model_tag='prithivida/parrot_adequacy_on_BART'):
      4     from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer
----> 5     self.nli_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_tag)
      6     self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_tag)
      7 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/modeling_auto.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
   1357         config = kwargs.pop("config", None)
   1358         if not isinstance(config, PretrainedConfig):
-> 1359             config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
   1360 
   1361         for config_class, model_class in MODEL_FOR_SEQUENCE_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING.items():

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/configuration_auto.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    201 
    202         """
--> 203         config_dict, _ = PretrainedConfig.get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    204 
    205         if "model_type" in config_dict:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py in get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    249                 f"- or '{pretrained_model_name_or_path}' is the correct path to a directory containing a {CONFIG_NAME} file\n\n"
    250             )
--> 251             raise EnvironmentError(msg)
    252 
    253         except json.JSONDecodeError:

OSError: Can't load config for 'prithivida/parrot_adequacy_on_BART'. Make sure that:

- 'prithivida/parrot_adequacy_on_BART' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or 'prithivida/parrot_adequacy_on_BART' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
```

`Is there a way to fix this error. May be by uploading the file manually? As it calls the below lines for style=0:`

```
class Styleformer():

  def __init__(self,  style=0):
    from transformers import AutoTokenizer
    from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
    from styleformer import Adequacy

    self.style = style
    self.adequacy = Adequacy()
    self.model_loaded = False

    if self.style == 0:
      self.ctf_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("prithivida/informal_to_formal_styletransfer")
      self.ctf_model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("prithivida/informal_to_formal_styletransfer")
      print("Casual to Formal model loaded...")
      self.model_loaded = True
```

`Note: When I run same thing on Google Colab, It automatically downloads few files and works fine. I do not know which file or models it downloads. It's a bit confusing. Please help.`